# Passing Array to model function query codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my function I want to put array values in IN() clause but it is not working
    Here `$ids` is the array passing to it.

```
    function get_school_students_data($ids){
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM screening_answers where uid 
    IN(".implode(',',$ids).")");
    $result=$query->result_array();
     return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean not working? Throws error or wrong result?

Comment: Wrong result Only first index of array is showing

Comment: Try `echo "SELECT * FROM screening_answers where uid 
    IN(".implode(',',$ids).")";` and see if it is producing the expected query. If it looks good then there is no data in your database. If it looks wrong then fix the SQL. If the `$ids` contain letters then you need to build your `in()` clause to use quotes around your values.

Comment: Add $this->db->last_query(); before your return and check the SQL.
Also you return the num_rows() and not a data set. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: Yes i want number of rows that are 2 ids according to my dummy data but its showing 1 id only that is the first index of array $ids

Comment: @GhulamMuhammadMujtaba Please have a look at my answer...

Comment: SELECT * FROM screening_answers where uid IN(282)

Comment: @GermanDrulyk this is the echo query

Comment: So `$ids` needs more array elements. Try `echo '<pre>'.print_r($ids, true).'</pre>';` and you will see the issue.

Comment: @GermanDrulyk i use it and here the result is right but when i pass this array to model function the index 1 is only executed

Comment: You are wrong. You are clearly only passing in index 1 to the `get_school_students_data()` function so it is acting properly. You will have to examine the code which calls the `get_school_students_data()` function.

Comment: $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM screening_answers where uid IN(".implode(',',$ids[0]).")");
          $result.=$query->result_array();
           return $query->num_rows();

Comment: when i put index 0 or 1 in $ids[0] then it works other wise its not

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->where_in('uid',$ids);
```

So in model

```
function get_school_students_data($ids){
    $this->db->where_in('uid',$ids);//$ids should be an array like array('20','15','22','42','86')
    $query = $this->db->get("screening_answers");
    $result=$this->db->result_array();// no need of this in your scenario
    return $this->db->num_rows();
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure `$ids` is an array please post your controller code also...

Comment: $student = $this->school_model-
>get_school_students($institute);
         foreach ($student as $ids); 
         
         $record = $this->school_model->get_school_students_data($ids);   
        
          $this->load->view('analyst/header_a');
          $this->load->view('analyst/annexure_a');
              $this->load->view('analyst/footer');

Comment: @GhulamMuhammadMujtaba I am unable to understand `foreach ($student as $ids);` Why there is a semicolon `;` at the end of foreach...  ??

Comment: @GhulamMuhammadMujtaba this is the best way to use array inside "IN()" for mysql..don't understand why have down voted this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use the active record of codeigniter

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM screening_answers where uid 
IN(".implode(',',$ids).")");
```

become

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('screening_answer');
$this->db->where_in('uid',$ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this its work for me**
//For Simple/Random Search

```
 function search($designation){
        $this->db->select("*");
        foreach($designation as $single_data) $this->db->or_like("designation",$single_data);
        $this->db->order_by('rand()');
        $this->db->limit(100);
        $this->db->from('content');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```